# Saving PDF Calibration in Autodesk Forge Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, calibration

Does the Calibration measurements performed on the PDF file in Autodesk Forge Viewer can be saved along with the PDF, so that opening the PDF again can show the saved calibrations.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the calibration factor with this function :
`var calibrationFactor = viewer.getExtension("Autodesk.Measure").calibrationTool.getCalibrationFactor()`

And then you can apply it using :
`viewer.getExtension("Autodesk.Measure").calibrationTool.setCalibrationFactor(calibrationFactor)`

Comment: Thanks Alex. Can we get this data at the time of unloading the viewer or any special event where we need to catch this? Thanks !

Comment: You can subscribe to this event to get the calibration data every time a new calibration is done `viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.MeasureCommon.Events.FINISHED_CALIBRATION, (e)=>{ /* your code to get and store calibration factor here */})`

Comment: Thanks Alex, that was helpful. One more question, are Calibration Factor and Calibration size same or different? How can we save the Calibration size given into the panel on the next load? Thanks for your help !

Comment: I think the **Calibration Size** is the value you provide for the selected length. The **Calibration Factor** is the ratio calculated with this size and the length between the 2 points. When you subscribe to the event, the callback parameter (e in my example) is an object that gives you : scaleFactor, size and units. One way to save these values is to request your server to get / write values into database.

Comment: Can you mark my answer as accepted if it answers your question ?